# BeautifulSoup SoupStrainer doesn't work when element has multiple classes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try

```
necessaryStuffOnly = SoupStrainer("table",{"class": "views-table"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(vegetables,parse_only=necessaryStuffOnly)
```

without luck on a table like this:

```
<div class="view-content">
  <table class="views-table sticky-enabled cols-20">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>blablaba</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>more blablabla</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and this does work for the div

```
SoupStrainer("div",{"class": "view-content"})
```

Can't a SoupStrainer like this filter on element with multiple classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparision that's used is a literal equality check, so the following works:

```
soup('table', {'class': "views-table sticky-enabled cols-20"})
```

You can get it to match by doing by passing a function as to the filter:

```
soup('table', {'class': lambda L: 'views-table' in L.split()})
```

It might be worth checking the version you're using, because I have a feeling this shouldn't be the case anymore... update: yup, here you go https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/410304

Comment: lambda function works but the bug fix is for search only? or also for the SoupStrainer?

Comment: @Dieter Pass - I just seem to recall from ages back something similar - and haven't really had any cause to look into it in any depth... I normally use `lxml.html` for most things now anyway...

Comment: the html I'm scraping is sometimes really messy which is the reason why I am using BeautifulSoup. Should I consider pure lxml?

Comment: @Dieter You can use lxml but specify beautifulsoup as the parser - then you get the best of both worlds - I'd give that a go